# Minus 1 from column value?

Tags: sql, joomla, phpmyadmin, virtuemart

How would I go about subtracting "1" for all the values of a column in the database?

I have table:
products

Columns:
custom_id --- 
customfield_value

I want to reduce the value of "customfield_value" by 1 with a query.

I tried this but it was not working:

```
UPDATE `products` 
SET `customfield_value` = (
   SELECT 
    customfield_value
   WHERE
    custom_id = 22
    customfield_value - 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the nested select?

```
UPDATE products
    SET customfield_value = customfield_value - 1;
```

This affects *all* columns in the table -- as your question asks.  Of course, you can add a `WHERE` clause for a particular row or set of rows:

```
UPDATE products
    SET customfield_value = customfield_value - 1
    WHERE custom_id = 22;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon appreciate it! I was just struggling a bit with the layout/syntax. Though this got it working. Many thanks again.

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind. Can I set up a query like this to run automatically after a certain number of hours?

Comment: @MailBlade . . . If you have a job scheduler for scheduling queries.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon I will have a look into that! Appreciate it.